# Apache Logs / Grep Command Help Needed

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, grep

I need to be able to see all requests made by an IP in a given day.

I'm not familiar with grep and was wondering if anyone could give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can limit the search results to an specific day?

I like awk for a question like this; you can match multiple fields in a single command.  If we assume you're using a standard Apache log format, field 1 is the IP address and field 5 is the date of the access:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /8\.8\.8\.8/ && $4 ~ /15\/Dec\/2009/ { print }' /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

`awk` processes each line in a file and splits it on whitespace into variables named `$1`, `$2`, and so on.  You can match them with the `$2 ~ /REGEX/` syntax, and you can match on multiple fields.

Apache stores the date in the ridiculous DD/Mon/YYYY format, so you need to escape the `/` character, which makes matching dates a little unwieldy.

A solitary `{ print }` will print the whole line (awk also knows this as `$0`).  If you only want to emit specific fields, you can add those to the print statement.  If you only wanted to print the requested URI, you would do:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /8\.8\.8\.8/ && $4 ~ /15\/Dec\/2009/ { print $7 }' /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Since the request URI is field 7 in the log.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your log is at `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and assuming that your Apache logs are in common or combined format:

```
$ grep "^w\.x\.y\.z" /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

e.g. to search for 127.0.0.1

```
$ grep "^127\.0\.0\.1" /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway I can limit the search results to an specific day?

Comment: Something like: `grep "^127\.0\.0\.1.* \[15\/Dec\/2009" /var/log/apache2/access.log`

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative to the above answers, without the "complexity" (for some) of regex.

I first check (tail) the log file for the date format, like so:

```
tail filename
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:08 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:09 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:12 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:13 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:14 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:15 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:16 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2017:18:33:17 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 155
```

then i simple copy/paste the date as a literal string, like so:

```
grep "31/Jan/2017" file | grep 127.0.0.1
```

or, sometimes i need to narrow it down to the hour, so i just copy the hour with it:

```
grep "31/Jan/2017:18" file | grep 127.0.0.1
```